# Git merge on files in repository to the files on my local pc

Tags: git

I have a few people working on the files. I know that I can use `git commit` and `git push` to put my files to merge with the files in the repository.

What I want to know is the other way around. If other people updated the files in the repository, how do I get those latest files to merge with the files in my pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git pull
```

This will suffice until you get conflicts.

Further reading: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Answer (score 0):

"git pull" will do fetch and merge task.
And there is material you could check.
[git-merge](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge)